# Export from Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, export, telerik-grid, radgrid

RadGrid can export its data to csv but default implementation doesnt fit terms of huge tables because it generates result export file in memory which doesnt work when you get like 5000k records.

I use RadGrid with LinqDataSource, and my tables contains millions of records. Im thinking on how to implement more smarty export. I have already had task subsystem running processes in threads etc, so what i really need is to get current RadGrid query with filters, sorting but without page limitation. This query i would put in my service which will «run» it and read record by record into file.

Does anybody know how to get current query, expression or whatever from RadGrid which would help to perfom the same query and read the data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the single solution is to limit the number of the exported records:

[Radgrid exporting large dataset](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-exporting-large-dataset.aspx)